# Sliding div left and right jumps

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a sliding div which shows some content when you click on a image. Everything is working fine except that when you click the previous arrow/close button the div jumps. It closes and then opens again.

I only want to close the div when that tiny arrow is clicked. 
I really can't see what I am doing wrong...

I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/meules/o2x9s6gk/1/) to show what I mean. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Below my code and HTML:

```
 $('#sets .set').each( function(){

    $(this).click(function(){
      if($(this).hasClass('open')){

         $('.close').click(function(){

           $('#sets .set').removeClass('open');

          $('.products',this).animate({
            width: 'toggle'},500, function() {
              $('#sets .product').fadeOut();
              $(this).css('z-index', '5');
              $(this).removeClass('open');

              $(this).hide();
              $(this).css('z-index', '5');
              $(this).removeClass('open');
            });
           });
      } else {


        $('#sets .set .product').hide();
        $('#sets .set .products').hide();
        $('#sets .set').css('z-index', '5');
        $('#sets .set').removeClass('open');
        $('#sets .set .products').removeClass('open');

        $(this).addClass('open');
        $(this).css('z-index', '1000');
        $('.products',this).animate({
          width: 'toggle'},500, function(){
            $('#sets .product').fadeIn();
            $(this).addClass('open');  
            $(this).css('z-index', '1000');
          });

      }      
    });
  });
```

HTML

```
<div id="sets" class="clearfix">

  <div class="set">
    <div class="mededeling">
      <div class="mededeling-txt">
        click me!
      </div>
      <div class="mededeling-bg"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">

      <div class="products">
        <div class="close"></div>

        <div class="product">
          some awesome content
            some awesome content
            some awesome content
            some awesome contentsome awesome content
            some awesome content
        </div>

        <div class="set-bestellen">
          <div class="set-bestellen-kop">Order?</div>
          <div class="total price"></div>
          <div class="link">

              <a title="Add to cart" class="btn-wd trigger" href="/cart"><span>Add to cart</span></a>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!-- .products -->
    </div><!-- .right -->
    <div class="img">

      <img src="" />

    </div>

  </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your click handlers and animations are messed up. For example on each `set` click, you are creating a new `close` click handler. Which is unnecessary.

I tried to clean it up a bit to give you an idea, it still needs some work though to being able to use multiple sets on one page for example:

http://jsfiddle.net/o2x9s6gk/2/

```
 $('#sets .set').click(function () {
     if (!$(this).hasClass('open')) {
         $('#sets .set .product').hide();
         $('#sets .set .products').hide();
         $('#sets .set').css('z-index', '5');
         $('#sets .set').removeClass('open');
         $('#sets .set .products').removeClass('open');

         $(this).addClass('open');
         $(this).css('z-index', '1000');
         $('.products', this).animate({
             width: 'toggle'
         }, 500, function () {
             $('#sets .product').fadeIn();
             $(this).addClass('open');
             $(this).css('z-index', '1000');
         });

     }
 });


 $('.close').click(function () {
     $('#sets .product').fadeOut(200, function () {
         $('.products').animate({
             width: 'toggle'
         }, 500, function () {
             $('#sets .set').removeClass('open');
             $(this).css('z-index', '5');
             $(this).removeClass('open');

             $(this).hide();
             $(this).css('z-index', '5');
             $(this).removeClass('open');
         });
     });

 });
```

Comment: Ok thx for your answer. It is helpfull... Just one question what would be a good way then to use your code with multiple `sets` on one page?? Id's is not an option right??

Comment: @Meules in the 'close' click, you'd have to check which close button has been clicked, or target only the parent `product` panel. As it is now it'll close all `product` panels on the page. For example instead of `$('#sets .product')` you could use `$(this).next('.product')`.